# Using the time library in Python to make a routine

Tags: python, timer

My goal for this code is to ultimately make a timing routine for some lights. Essentially have a two fields that a user fills saying when a light should come on and when it should come off. I'm starting from ground zero right now so I'm trying to cover the basics.

I've gotten a timer down using code from another post:

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

x=datetime.today()
y=x.replace(day=x.day, hour=1, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta_t=y-x

secs=delta_t.seconds+1

def hello_world():
    print "hello world"
    #...

t = Timer(secs, hello_world)
t.start()
```

This prints hello world at a certain time everyday. The only problem with this code is that once it completes the routine, it does not restart. I'd like for one that continues refreshing. In addition to that, I'd like to print out a time every second. I tried using a while loop but I end up getting stuck in there so my hello world statement never actually prints:

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

x=datetime.today()
y=x.replace(day=x.day+1, hour=1, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta_t=y-x

secs=delta_t.seconds+1

def hello_world():
    print "hello world"
    #...

t = Timer(secs, hello_world)
t.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use run() to restart the thread:

```
def hello_world():
   global t 
   print ("hello world")
   t.run()

t = Timer(secs, hello_world)
t.start()
```

Than you can make a new thread

```
  def hello_world():
       global sec
       print ("hello World")
       Timer(sec,hello_word).start()
```

and you can also use a CRON job